# Scala: Error type mismatch

Tags: scala

I am struggling with the type system.  I get a "error: type mismatch" at the line

```
handler.addJob(job1)
```

It says `found "MessageEvent" required "Event"`

I think that I need to somehow change the `addJob` method to pass in any `Job` with a type that extends `Event` but I can't figure out how to do that.

Also the line

```
var jobs = List[Job[Event]]()
```

should probably take a job with a subtype of `Event` but again I don't know how to do that.  Any help is appreciated.

-Eric

```
class EventHandler {
  var jobs = List[Job[Event]]()

  def receive(event: Event) {
    jobs.foreach {
      _.processEvent(event)
    }
  }

  def addJob(job: Job[Event]) {
    jobs = job :: jobs
  }
}

class Job[T <: Event] {
  var steps = List[(T => Unit)]()

  def addStep(step: (T => Unit)) {
    steps = step :: steps
  }

  def processEvent(event: T): Boolean = {
    steps.foreach(_.apply(event))
    return true
  }
}

class AppTest {
  def testApp {
    val handler = new EventHandler()
    val job1 = new Job[MessageEvent]
    job1.addStep {
      println(_)
    }
    handler.addJob(job1)
    handler.receive(new MessageEvent(new Message()))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problems you mention are easy to fix:

```
class EventHandler {
  var jobs = List[Job[_]]()

  def receive(event: Event) {
    jobs.foreach {
      _.processEvent(event)
    }
  }

  def addJob(job: Job[_]) {
    jobs = job :: jobs
  }
}
```

But this shows another problem with the `receive` method: you need each `job` to process any `Event`. This can be fixed using `Manifest`s to work around type erasure:

```
class Job[T <: Event : ClassManifest] {
  val clazz: Class[T] = implicitly[ClassManifest[T]].asInstanceOf[Class[T]]
  var steps = List[(T => Unit)]()

  def addStep(step: (T => Unit)) {
    steps = step :: steps
  }

  def processEvent1(event: Event): Boolean = {
    try {
      processEvent(clazz.cast(event))
    }
    catch {
      case e: ClassCastException => false
    }
  }

  def processEvent(event: T): Boolean = {
    steps.foreach(_.apply(event))
    return true
  }
}
```

Comment: If you like an answer, you should vote it up (see FAQ, "How do I ask questions here?").

Answer (score 0):

Changing `addJobs`:

```
def addJob[T <: Event](job: Job[T]) {
  jobs = job :: jobs
}
```

But `jobs` won't work with that, since `Job[MessageEvent]` is not a `Job[Event]`. The only way to get that is to make `Job` co-variant, but, unfortunately, you can't make `Job` co-variant as it is.

Why don't you, instead, completely removes `Job`'s parameterization and use `Event` internally? You can then use `T <: Event` (like above in `addJob`) with `addStep` and `processEvent`, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, it looks as though you'll be building the `Job` and `EventHandler` instances statically.  In this case, you really don't need those classes at all!

Starting with `Job`.  This performs two roles:

1. maintain a list of `T => Unit` functions
2. execute those functions

*(it's also worth noting that `::` prepends, so steps will be executed in the reverse of the order they were added)*

Building and maintaining that list of functions at runtime (within a mutable list) can be completely avoided if you already know what they'll be when the thing compiles.  This is most naturally done with an aggregate function:

```
val job = (m: MessageEvent) => {
  log.debug(m)
  println(m)
  somethingElse(m)
}
```

Instead of holding a `List[Job[Event]]`, this means that `EventHandler` now holds a `List[(T => Unit)]` (as `Job` previously did).  So rinse and repeat...